# What variable stays true within a specific fixed time interval?

Tags: c#, time, hash

I have a cool method to generate a 6 digit hash for phone verification.

The code is never stored and but is computed by manipulating that particular phone plus some other variable including the issuing hour which leads to code issued at the end of the hour expiring before users have the chance to use them.

How can i get a time variable that stays constant during a certain time interval to include it so that the code automatically expire after that?.

```
public string getTimeVariable(long minutes)
{
  var now=DateTime.Now;
  //Some imprementation I cant think of....
}

public bool verifyVariable(string variable)
{
   //Some other implementation to return true if specified minutes haven't elapsed since variable was issued
}
```

Comment: You need some cookie that expires after a certain period of time? Your question is pretty unclear. You can´t store code anywhere, you just compile it into an assembly.

Comment: No  cookie just a variable

Comment: Maybe you should show some code to illustrate what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ok let me edit the question

Comment: You mean something like `var now = DateTime.UtcNow(); now = now.Date.AddHours(now.Hour)`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere  I have added code to illustrate hope it helps

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek exactly but i want the output of such function to stay fixed for a particular time

Comment: Well, rounding up current time up a full hour will make it say the same for an hour, won't it?

Comment: yes that is what am using but they are people requesting code at the end of an hour and getting a code that expires quickly.. How do you round up to avoid this?

Comment: I have the registeredDate varible @FCin, I was thinking if 12pm stays 12pm for an hour... if i use it will be valid for that hour.. put for my purpose an hour is very long and a minute too short, so i need someting in between i am starting to think i will need two of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code, it does what You want by simply being open to having view on what were the codes that were valid over last period. The code changes every second now. You can alter the period size and the number of past periods still considered valid.

By the way - what is Your cool method exactly?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class Test {

 private static long secret = 0xdeadbeef;
 private static int digits = 6;
 private static int period_size_in_seconds = 1;

 public string phonenumber;
 public int validperiods;

 private string reference(long delta) {
  // get current minute (UTC)
  long now = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToFileTimeUtc();
  now /= (period_size_in_seconds * 10000000);
  // factor in phone number
  var inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(phonenumber);
  long mux = 0;
  foreach(byte elem in inputBytes) {
    mux ^= elem;
    mux <<= 1;
   }
   // limit number of digits
  long mod = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Pow(10, digits)) - 1; // how many digits?
  // apply time shift for validations
  now -= delta;
  // and play a little bit
  now *= mux; // factor in phone number
  now ^= secret; // play a bit
  now >>= 1; // with the number
  if (0 != (now & 0x1)) { // to make the code 
   now >>= 1; // read about LFSR to learn more
   now ^= secret; // less deterministic
  }
  now = Math.Abs(now);
  now %= mod; // keep the output in range
  return now.ToString().PadLeft(digits, '0');
 }

 public string getTimeVariable() {
  return reference(0);
 }

 public bool verifyVariable(string variable) {
  for (int i = 0; i < validperiods; i++) {
   if (variable == reference(i)) {
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 public void test() {
  phonenumber = "+48602171819";
  validperiods = 900;
  string code = getTimeVariable();

  if (verifyVariable(getTimeVariable()))
   System.Console.Write("OK1");

  if (verifyVariable(code))
   System.Console.Write(" OK2");

  Thread.Sleep(2*1000*period_size_in_seconds);

  if (verifyVariable(code)) {
   System.Console.WriteLine(" OK3");
  }

  System.Console.WriteLine(code);
 }

 public static void Main() {
  (new Test()).test();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the cool method just hashes na the number and transform is in a 6 digit number in a way that reduces collition i will try this out as soon as i reach my computer...